# Showing up DataProcessing on SplashScreen Label c#

Tags: c#, splash-screen

The screen is already finished I used the Devexpress SplashScreen. It opens at the beginning and closes when all data is loaded until the main application opens. Now my question is how to get the data loaded in the background into a label so that the user sees something happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [SplashScreenManager.SendCommand](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraSplashScreen.SplashScreenManager.SendCommand(System.Enum-System.Object)) for communication between the application and the splash screen

**Form Code**

```
        private void btnShowSplashScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            // Open a Splash Screen
            SplashScreenManager.ShowForm(this, typeof(SplashScreen1), true, true, false);

            // The splash screen will be opened in a separate thread. To interact with it, use the SendCommand method.
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                SplashScreenManager.Default.SendCommand(SplashScreen1.SplashScreenCommand.SetProgress, i);
                //To process commands, override the SplashScreen.ProcessCommand method.
                Thread.Sleep(25);
            }

            // Close the Splash Screen.
            SplashScreenManager.CloseForm(false);
        }
```

Splash code

```
        public override void ProcessCommand(Enum cmd, object arg) {
            base.ProcessCommand(cmd, arg);
            SplashScreenCommand command = (SplashScreenCommand)cmd;
            if (command == SplashScreenCommand.SetProgress) {
                int pos = (int)arg;
                progressBarControl1.Position = pos;
            }
        }


        public enum SplashScreenCommand {
            SetProgress,
            Command2,
            Command3
        }
```